# JDBC used to validate if a user exists but always returns false?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Trying to use JDBC to handle some logic for validating if a user and password are in the DB and correct.

The method should return true if they are in the DB or false if not

I've tried changing the methods and it always either lets any user in, even if they dont exist, or no one in, even if they are in the DB.

Can someone explain how to fix this, funnily enough it was working the other day but I've changed something and unsure what...

JDBC code

```
    public boolean checkUser(String username, String pass) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {
            //loading drivers for mysql
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

          //creating connection with the database
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/workoutDB", "root", "root");
                System.out.println("username = " + username);
                System.out.println("pass = " + pass);

                String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + pass + "')";
                System.out.println("lo " + sql);
                Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                out.println(valid);

                if(rs.next()) {
                    valid = true;
                    out.println(valid);
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                }



        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            out.println(e);
        }

        out.println(valid);
        return valid;

    }
```

I've included an image of the console output, the username test, with password tes is in the db.

[image]

Sorry it was another class which does the same thing I added the prepared too, it also always returns true or false regardless of if the condition is met.

```
public boolean checkUser(String username, String pass) {

        boolean valid = true;

        try {
            //loading drivers for mysql
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

            //creating connection with the database
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/workoutDB", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("username = " + username);
            System.out.println("pass = " + pass);

            //String sql = "SELECT username  FROM users WHERE (username = '" + username + "')";
            //String sql2 = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE (password = '" + pass + "')";
            //System.out.println(sql);
            //System.out.println(sql2);
            //Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            //ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            //ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery(sql2);

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where username=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, username);
            out.println("ps "+ps);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            out.println("ps "+ps);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            valid = !rs.next();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            out.println(e);
        }

        out.println(valid);

        return valid;

    }
```

Comment: if you would return a row on executing the query, then there should be 3 prints for valid, so what I find is that there are only 2 prints so it must be that the query is not returning any rows. So the problem must be with the query or database

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on the database? Also, you shouldn't use concatenation to craft the query but rather used prepared statements : you're currently vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement` for this. Consider the case where the user enters `tes or password is not null' as his password.

Comment: Thankyou, I've actually changed it to a Prepared statement a few hours ago with no luck, also not too worried about sql injections as its only a local project :)

Comment: In your `PreparedStatement` code you're doing `valid = !rs.next();`, so valid is false when you have a row.

Comment: Even if it is a local project, I suggest you try to learn yourself best practices like using parameterized queries. It will reinforce those tricks, and -hopefully - prevent you from using unsafe things out of habit when doing real work.

Comment: Hi Mark, that was to bypass the check to complete another area, otherwise it wouldn't authenticate.Can I ask how I would improve the query on the second set of code? Do you mean remove the SELECT * and make it more specific?